# MVC Save data from View and Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am currently trying to create an application that asks the user a set of questions. I want the application to save data from the view and once the user clicks the next button, it saves the data and shows the next question. As I am new to MVC I am really struggling to get my head around things.

I want the questions from the Questions table  to load in the UnRegistered view. I then want to save the questions Id along with the answer in the RegistrationQuestions table along with things such as timestamp, UserID from the session, answer etc. In short I want to select from the QuestionsManager table and then insert to the RegistrationQuestions table.

I am getting myself confused where the view is concerned, as I have spent so long using ASP.NET...

**The Model:**

```
public class RegistrationQuestionsContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<RegistrationQuestions> RegistrationDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuestionsManager> QuestionDetails { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This tables stores the result of the questions asked
/// </summary>
[Table("RegistrationQuestions")]
public class RegistrationQuestions
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string fldUserID { get; set; }
    public int fldQuestionId { get; set; }             
    public string fldAnswer { get; set; }
    public string fldUOM { get; set; }
    public DateTime fldTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public int fldCurrentPosition { get; set; }
    public bool fldRegistrationCompleted { get; set; }       
}

/// <summary>
/// This tables stores questions that are to be asked
/// </summary>
[Table("Questions")]
public class QuestionsManager
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string fldQuestion { get; set; }
    public int fldOptionId { get; set; }
    public bool fldQuestionActive { get; set; }
}
```

**The controller:**

```
   [Authorize]   
    public class RegistrationQuestionsController : Controller
    {
    private RegistrationQuestionsContext db = new RegistrationQuestionsContext();        

    public RegistrationQuestionsController()
    {
        //            
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UnRegistered()
    {
        //Determines whether registration questions have all been completed
        var Progress = (from o in db.RegistrationDetails.ToList() where o.fldUserID == User.Identity.GetUserId() select (bool?) o.fldRegistrationCompleted);
            bool RegistrationCompleted = Progress.First().Value;

            //If the user has not completed the registration we jump into here
            if (!RegistrationCompleted)
            {
                //This detmerines the current question number that the user is at. This is so if they bail out we know where they were if they log in again.
                var Position = (from o in db.RegistrationDetails.ToList() where o.fldUserID == User.Identity.GetUserId() select (int?) o.fldCurrentPosition);
                int CurrentPosition = Position.First().Value;

                //I want this Question to appear on the View
                var Question = (from o in db.QuestionDetails.ToList() where o.Id == CurrentPosition select o.fldQuestion);
                string CurrentQuestion = Question.First().ToString();

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {   
                    //I then want to save the details from the view along with further details from the RegistrationQuestions model in a different table.
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("/RegistrationQuestions/UnRegistered/");
                }

                return Redirect("/RegistrationQuestions/UnRegistered/");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/RegistrationQuestions/Registered");

            }          
    }        

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

**The View:**

```
@model  Foodsnap.Models.QuestionsManager

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registration Questions";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
    You have not completed the registration, please click the button to continue.
    </br>
    YOU ARE UNREGISTERED!!!
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.fldQuestion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.fldQuestion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.fldQuestion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Next Question" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is too much code. What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: The page loads fine, but I cannot get the question to load and I have no idea how to save the data. I have spent all week on the MVA site trying to learn it, but it left me more confused.

Comment: I would like a pointer to the correct approach, so I can at least understand how it is supposed to work

Comment: You are missing a lot of pieces, But most importantly you need to get a handle on how the controller generates the view. your controller method UnRegistered() needs to return a model and a view route/location. 
I think you should take the time a do a quick tutorial

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go. It is certainly the controller bit that is confusing me.

Comment: the symptoms you have are typical when you skip the steps along the learning curve, tutorials, examples, documentation, these things are very well documented.

Comment: You need to redirect to a method which displays the question, and pass it the `Id` of the next question to be asked. Then in that method, get the question based on the `Id` and return it to the view.